# How to fix the stretchy mesh deform error after apply automatic weights

Tags: mesh, rigging, weight-painting, rigify, pose-mode

I'm having some trouble fixing my character's weird stretchy meshes after using automatic weights with rigify. Specifically, the mouth and arm look strange. Could you look at this link I'm sharing to see if there's something off with the rig or mesh deform? [image]

[image]

[image]

Please don't forget to demonstrate pictures, gifs, or upload blends files. to make it easy to understand.

Comment: @Logan Thanks for the illustrations and share.. ( Some of the commentary here is not needed any more. I think it's OK for it to go, now. )

Comment: 1) check the face orientation. The body mesh has flipped normals. 2) for the shoes, apply the mirror modifier 3) in edit mode, select the shoelaces and separate them into an individual object. Then automatic weights will work.